# How to make Rails render a view and automatically scroll down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an obnoxiously large landing page with a registration form in the middle of it. If I submit the form and validation fails, I want to render the landing page again, but I want it be scrolled down to the registration form so they can see the errors and make edits. Is this possible to jump down to the form with the `render` method, or do I need to do  `redirect_to "account/new#theFormID"`?

I would rather not do a redirect because you have to save the form information in a session, repopulate the form, et cetera, and I want to stick the conventional

```
if @resource.save then redirect_to ...
else render "new"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

```
redirect_to profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall")
```

That is how you pass anchors.

Comment: Good to know, though it's not what I asked. How do I do this with "render"?

Comment: You can only do this with redirect.

Comment: That's what I was afraid. Put it as an answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: This is marked as the answer but clearly it is not. @another-sam has properly answered the question: using a `render` in the controller instead of a `redirect`. Also, see dupe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068887/rails-render-action-to-target-anchor-tag

Answer (score 26):

Put the anchor directive on the form and you can still rely on :render from the controller...

```
form_for(@my_model, :url => { :action => "create" , :anchor => "my_anchor" })
```

Comment: Man, why people voted you down! That sweet piece of your knowledge enlighted my small dark room for a few real minutes!! I have the ambition to have an app where most of the features are working even without javascript and that's really gorgeous option! thx a lot, I will use it with pleasure: `form_for(@reply, :url => create_reply_post_comment_path(@post, @comment, :anchor => "reply_comment_#{@comment.id}")`

Comment: Wow, this is great. Didn't expect to be able to do this, was a pleasant surprise of an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I scrolled to an anchor with `render` using a global var and Javascript (as hinted by Ibrahim).

On my controller I had this:

```
@anchor = "my_anchor"
render :action => "edit"
```

And on my page, I checked if I had a global @anchor, and if so, roll to it with Javascript:

```
<% if @anchor %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.hash = "<%= @anchor %>";
  </script>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

And another thing... if it's a link like I'm actually using, you have to add a unique `param` so the browser thinks it's submitting something new, otherwise it just refreshes without hitting the server.  I'm using:

```
link_to "REFRESH", refresh_my_model_path(@my_model, :anchor => "my_anchor", :options => {:id => Time.now} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript?

```
<script>
window.location.hash="ANCHOR";
</script>
```

Comment: Just make sure the javascript is only invoked if there is a validation error. =)