# Rails: Render to anchor tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, anchor

I have a few jquery tabs on a page, and I'd like a specific one to render on a 'render' call in my controller.

In short, the url I'd like to retrieve is

```
render '/accounts/index#disabled_accounts'
```

I've tried specifying the anchor tag, the above call, and a few other shots-in-the-dark, but so far nothing works. Any ideas on whether this is possible (and if so how) would be very appreciated.

Cheers...

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean, do you want a specific tab to have focus (be active, visible) when you open the page?

Comment: Yes - but as called through rails' "render" method. In short, accessing anchors through rails' render.

Comment: See my answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12563866/869616