# Rails 3: Rendering actions with named anchors/fragments after failed form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

The edit view for one of my models contains tabs that utilize anchors in the url to switch between settings such as model/1/edit#tab1 and model/1/edit#tab2. Is there a way to redirect to these anchors after submitting the edit form but failing to save due to errors? My current code is below:

```
  def update
    @user = Product.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Your user has been created"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit' //want to render here with an anchor
    end
  end
```

I would like to store the url containing the anchor before form submit and then re-render the form with the same anchor while rendering error messages. Any ideas?

Comment: I think that right way to do it is to use jquery script to change tab visibility on page load.

Comment: See my answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12563866/869616

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way was to use [jquery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to save last opened tab and then set default tab using saved cookie.