# Rails ContactUs model in single pages controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

Hi have simple rails site with no models, its used just for serving static pages.

The site has a Pages controller, but this is only serving up one home page made of partials.

Like such in the `app/views/pages/home.html.erb`

```
<%= render 'layouts/about' %>
<%= render 'layouts/services' %>
<%= render 'layouts/rooms' %>
<%= render 'layouts/breakfast' %>
<%= render 'layouts/guestbook' %>
<%= render 'layouts/contact' %>
```

The home page uses some html5/javascript which autoscrolls the page. So each section is prefaced with # to allow auto scrolling to that section.

```
   <li><a class="home" href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a class="services" href="#services">Tarrifs</a></li>
   <li><a class="portofolio" href="#portofolio">Rooms</a></li>
   <li><a class="breakfast" href="#breakfast">Breakfast</a></li>
   <li><a class="contact" href="#contact" >Contact </a></li>
   <li><a class="services" href="#services">Blog / Whats On.</a></li>
   <li><a class="guestbook" href="#guestbook">Guest Book</a></li>
   <li class="description">Take a look.</li>
```

This all works fine. 
[Dev site is here](http://young-atoll-4121.herokuapp.com/)

Now my question / issue is : I'd like to add a rails type ContactUS page.

Following various tutorials :

[Simple Contact Us](http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/)

[Rails 3 Contact us](http://www.rodrigoalvesvieira.com/formulario-contato-rails/)

They all point to having a message model,ActionMailer, and contact controller, which works if you want to have a separate contact controller.

I'm stuck at trying to figure how I can build a contactUs form but keep it the pages controller to allow the autoscrolling to work as using a contact controller seems to change all the URL routes. I know this probably isn't the Rails way, but any help would be great.

Hope that made sense. Any ideas ?

Comment: If your problem is solved using a single controller, why not just put the contact methods in that controller?

Comment: You could just `<%= render 'contact/form' %>` from the contact view  in your contact page in the pages controller. This would require creating a contact controller and view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do following:

Add a new model called "Form", app/models/form.rb

```
class Form
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true, email: true
  validates :message, presence: true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

modify your pages_controller:

```
def new
  @form = Form.new
end

def create
  @form = Form.new(params[:form])
  if @form.valid?
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thanks!")
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Add the form html code to your app/views/pages/home.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @form do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :email %>
   <%= f.email_field :email %>
 </div>

 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :message %>
   <%= f.text_area :message %>
 </div>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
 </div>
```

And that´s it, you have your build in contact form.

This code is collected from one of my gems on github:
https://github.com/mattherick/contact_form

For testing you can add this gem to your gemfile and run the files generators, described in the github readme.

Comment: Thanks I sort of go there in the end, the only issue I have now is site has a fancy template with javascript and html5 , which to be honest I'm not sure how it all works, but the main page is in scrollable sections  Upon the completion of the form I would like to stay at the contact section rather than the root. i.e http://site/#contact , rather than http://site/#home . Any ideas how I can pass url in redirect rather than home_path ?

Comment: maybe some of these answers could help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068887/rails-render-action-to-target-anchor-tag - so redirect like this way: redirect_to :action => 'page', :anchor => 'contact'