# how to set bookmark link in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i confuse to set bookmark link using render in controller. i set this in my controller

```
  def new
    @email = Email.new
    render layout: false 
  end

  def create  
    @email = Email.new(email_params)
    if @email.valid?
      @email = params[:email]      
      render layout: false
    else
      render 'new', layout: false
    end
  end
```

if it success create. i want it go to the page in specific ID let say that i want to go to id="headline".

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  <head>
<body>
  <div id="profile">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="headline">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="promo">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

how do i set that.

Comment: You can try redirect_to create_path(@email, anchor: 'headline')

Comment: Or you can give link in render like render '/create#headline'

Comment: @ShivanshNalwaya Are you sure `render '/create#headline'` will not look for a template with name _create#headline.html.erb_?

Comment: i found the solution, in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068887/rails-render-action-to-target-anchor-tag

Comment: @Ferdinand Ok great :)