# Interaction between controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

On my web app I have a login page which is in the Pages Controller called welcome.html.erb

Inside it has a simple form for login and a simple for for sign up, both on the same page.

If the user signs up with wrong credentials (like password confirmation wrong, or length of password and etc) the controller that handles this is the new method in the Users Controller.

Inside the new method it checks if a user is created, and if not I'd like it to return to the welcome method in Pages Controller, passing to it the errors that were created during the user's creation.

It seems that if I do a

```
redirect_to root_path
```

The error count of the signup is reset when returning to the root page. If instead I call some other action of the users controller I do see the errors.
But since all of the html code is in the welcome view I don't want to replicate the code in the users controller views as well..

Is there a way to pass that errors data to the pages controller?

The partial for the error is

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>

    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> from being saved:</h2>
        <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
        <ul>
            <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Which I call using

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Users controller I called

flash[:errors]=@user.errors
and then I changed the partial to be

```
<% if object.any? %>

    <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(object.count, "error") %> prohibited this <%= object.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase %> from being saved:</h2>
        <p>There were problems with the following fields:</p>
        <ul>
            <% object.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Which I called using

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object =>@user_errors %>
```

That solved the issue for now..

Answer (score 1):

```
redirect_to welcome_path
```

(Or whatever the actual path is.)

Comment: This does work, but it doesn't solve the problem, which I seem to not have explained it clearly after I understand it more. I edited the question better

Comment: @RailsN00b Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I edit the question. My problem isn't the redirect to root, but the reset of the errors of the login using a partial

Comment: @RailsN00b See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536428/rails-validation-over-redirect) and [this](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/12/20/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-set-flash-in-redirect_to); basically you need to keep the errors in flash.

Comment: but that means I need to write the errors myself and not use the model verification errors

Comment: @RailsN00b Why? It's a single line: `flash[:errors] = clone_with_errors(@example)`. At worst you'll have to iterate through them. But the only login error you should get is "cannot log in with username/password combo" (or similar) anything else gives away information.

Comment: I solved this with flash[:errors] but without the clone function. I added the solution in the question itself. Thanks

Comment: @RailsN00b Better to answer the question, and accept your own answer, although IMO I pretty much answered it.