# Displaying validation erors in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add comments to books (comments belongs to books), so I added this form to show page of books:

```
%h3 Add a comment:
= form_with(model: [ @book, @book.comments.build ], local: true) do |form|
  %p
    = form.text_area :content
  %p
    = form.submit "Add a comment"
```

It works, but I need to display model validation error for empty comments. I tried with:

```
  - if  @book.errors.any?
    %h2
      = pluralize(@book.errors.count, "error")
      prohibited this article from being saved:
    %ul
      - @book.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

(after "form_with" line), but nothing is happen. I think that @book.errors is wrong, but have no idea how to replace it.

Create method of my comments controller:

```
  def create
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @comment = @book.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
    redirect_to book_path(@book)
   end
  end
```

Comment: Wouldn't the errors be on the comment object?

Comment: I think errors are lost when you redirect, but you can use `flash` in that case - see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252783/passing-error-messages-through-flash

Comment: max is correct, when doing an if check on @comment.save most standard rails controllers will call render, rather than redirect.

Answer (score 0):

1 > comments_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
    @comment = @book.comments.create(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to book_path(@book)
    else
      redirect_back(fallback_location: book_path(@book))
    end
  end
```

2 > Replace `@book` to `@comment` as @comment object contains validations erros

```
  - if  @comment.errors.any?
    %h2
      = pluralize(@comment.errors.count, "error")
      prohibited this article from being saved:
    %ul
      - @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        %li= msg
```

Comment: 2 > i get "undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass", because of "form_with(model: [ @book, @book.comments.build ]" line