# Building a form related to a controller, in a view related to another one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm starting with Rails, and actually I'm trying to include a form (related to a controller A) inside a view (related to a controller B).

My problem is that when I include the form code inside my view, in case of failure I am always redirected to the controller A view... This is quite logic but also, besides rendering a custom template (the one initially related to controller B), I can't stay within my view and having the proper form errors... But when rendering a custom template I am still "redirected" and also the url is changed.

Is there a way to pass, in the controller A, a proper redirection to controller B, that allows me to keep access to the form errors? Or am I doing it wrong?

Thx in advance!

Comment: You can use `flash[:error]` if you need to redirect to another controller and pass your errors messages after a fail create action. Check this answer: [Passing error messages through flash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8253495/9541423)

Comment: Thx for your answer, but it is not a flash message that I want to display... It is a form error

Comment: what are you calling "form error" ?

Comment: The error commonly displayed inside the form, under each field having one

Answer (score 0):

You can use [form_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

```
<%= form_tag controller_a_path do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```