# form for separate controllers, errors not displaying

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a portfolio model which has_many assets (i.e an asset model).

My Portfolio Show view displays a current user's portfolio's assets but it also has a form to quickly add an asset to the current_portfolio.

```
 <%= form_for(@asset) do |f| %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :portfolio_id, params[:id]%>
      <%= f.text_field :asset_symbol %>
      ... some other fields for cost, shares held, etc
      <%= f.submit "Add Asset to current portfolio"%>
 <%end%>
```

Adding an asset works fine. Also, leaving the symbol field blank will prevent the asset from being added. However, the error does not show up when I submit the form.

I have `validates :asset_symbol, presence: true` in my model and I know it isn't saving. The issue is that the errors aren't being passed to my Portfolio Show view. It's as if the asset errors disappear between the Asset controller and the Portfolio Show view.

The show view has the following which should show errors

```
 <% if @asset.errors.any? %>
      <% @asset.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li> <%= msg %> </li>
      <% end %>
  <%end%>
```

@asset is defined my portfolio controller as `Asset.new`

The asset controller:

```
def create
    @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
    @asset.portfolio_id = params[:portfolio_id]
    @asset.save
    redirect_to portfolio_path(params[:portfolio_id])
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note if I were to `render 'portfolios/show'` the errors will display, but then I run into the issue that I am now on the link `/assets` and not `/portfolio/show/1`. This is important because I don't have the same variables in my Asset controller for `Create` and also because I can't reference the `:id` in `/assets`, something I can do in `/portfolio/show/1`. Therefore I don't think render is a solution.

Comment: What happens if you replace your redirect with: redirect_to portfolio_path(params[:portfolio_id], :asset => @asset)?  The reason your errors are not showing up is because the errors are attached to the @asset object, which is not being passed to the show page.

Comment: @AngeloChrysoulakis I tried that but nothing happens, it simply redirects me to `portfolio_path(params[:portfolio_id])` without any errors displaying. I think you are on the right path though, why did you choose :asset as the symbol to pass to the show page?

Comment: That's what I thought would probably happen.  Take a look at the following link for a complete solution -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536428/rails-validation-over-redirect  -- I prefer to deal with nuances like these with javascript.  So, in this case, for successful save, I would just update the asset.  Otherwise, I would prepend an error partial.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def create  
    @asset = Asset.new(params[:asset])
    @portfolio = Portfolio.find(params[:portfolio_id])
    @asset.portfolio_id = params[:portfolio_id]
    respond_to do |format|    
      if @asset.save
        format.html { redirect_to portfolio_path(params[:portfolio_id]) }
      else
       format.html { render :action => "show", :controller => "portfolio?" }
      end
    end
  end
```