# Rails 2.3.4 Persisting Model on Validation Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a standard html form post that is being persisted and validated with a rails model on the server side.

For the sake of discussion, lets call this a "car" model.

When

```
car.save
```

is invoked the validators fire and set a list of fields in error within the model.

How best can I get an object back that has the fields whose validation failed removed, i.e. such that I don't have to delete the fields on the form the user entered correctly?

The validation patterns they use are great but how do I get a hook to when the validation fails such that I can delete the bogus entries from the model?

I could see manually iterating over the errors list and writing a big case statement but that seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Don't do this (see comments) but if you must here is how:

I ended up using a call to

```
@car.invalid?
```

inside of a loop  to remove the invalid entries:

```
  params[:car].each do | key, array|
      if @car.errors.invalid?(key)
        @car[key.to_sym] = ''
      end
  end
  render :action=> 'new'
```

Note the use of the render here vs. redirect. Getting error messages to persist from the rails model validation across a redirect appears tricky, see:
[Rails validation over redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536428/rails-validation-over-redirect)

I still feel like there should be a helper method for this or a better way.

Comment: It's hard to draw a conclusion from your anonymized model name, but most of the time the UX is arguably better if you leave data in the fields. Keeping to the car example, I'd find it annoying if miskeying a model year as "212" instead of "2012" showed the error message "you must enter a year greater than 1950" and a BLANK year - as far as I remembered before hitting "Save", I *did* put in a valid one.

Comment: @MattJones I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, render the `new` action from your create action if validation fails, with an instance variable, `@car` populated from the user input (i.e., the `params` hash). Then, in your view, add a logic check (either an if block around the `form` or a ternary on the helpers, your choice) that automatically sets the value of the form fields to the `params` values passed in to @car if car exists. That way, the form will be blank on first visit and in theory only be populated on re-render in the case of error. In any case, they will not be populated unless `@car` is set.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. What I am after is a method to remove the invalid fields from the model.

Comment: I already have the working logic to repopulate the form on failure but it looks bad to put the bad data back in there.